# What file is node debugger breaking in?

Tags: node.js, node-debugger

I have some code which I am running in debug mode. As I understand it, this runs it through the standard [node.js debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

I'm frequently getting the following:

```
...
break in timers.js:77
...
```

Sometimes I have breakpoints at other files, but they always give absolute file paths, but in this case its just the file name. I cannot find a file with that name which has the content listed on `line 77`, nor can I find an explanation of how the debugger works in regards to this.

How can I find this `timers.js` file?

Comment: timers.js is a [core library](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.7/lib/timers.js) that's compiled in to the node binary.

Comment: Thanks @josh! "compiled in to the node binary" <-- meaning I can't access the source on my local machine? So... safe to assume that *all* files with non-absolute paths here are core libraries? If you (or someone) wants to put this info into an answer I'd be happy to up-vote and accept.

Comment: It is [possible](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) (though usually not normal) for non-builtin files to have no path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you see filenames with no path in the debugger, it means that the file is one of the [core libraries that are compiled in to the node binary](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/v0.12.7/lib).

If you want to dig in to source, make sure you're looking at the git tag that matches the version of node you're running.

The builtin files are:

- assert.js
- buffer.js
- child_process.js
- cluster.js
- console.js
- constants.js
- crypto.js
- dgram.js
- dns.js
- domain.js
- events.js
- freelist.js
- fs.js
- http.js
- https.js
- module.js
- net.js
- os.js
- path.js
- punycode.js
- querystring.js
- readline.js
- repl.js
- smalloc.js
- stream.js
- string_decoder.js
- sys.js
- timers.js
- tls.js
- tty.js
- url.js
- util.js
- vm.js
- zlib.js